# Exporting images attached to Geodatabase using QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, file-geodatabase, attachments, arcgis-survey123

I have an ESRI file geodatabase that was exported from their survey123 app, and the geodatabase has images attached to it.

I do not use ArcGIS, and was wondering how to export them from QGIS with their associated metadata.

Here's a Google Drive link to my gdb: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KIJMea9bhF0cZrMc-y1uCLjLpzScWukd?usp=sharing

Once open in QGIS, I can see the point features, and below that in my layers panel is a table with the photos' names, etc.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this easily in QGIS 3.6 and above (until QGIS 3.6 is officially released you can download a "nightly" version to test).

1. Load the "_ATTACH" table from the gdb into QGIS

[image]

2. From the Processing toolbox, search for "Extract Binary field". Double click to launch.
3. Select the binary "DATA" field for "binary field"
   [image]
4. Click the dropdown button to he right of "File name", select "edit", and enter an expression like `"GLOBALID" || '.jpg'`
   [image]
5. Pick a destination folder, and run.

All attachments will be exported to the selected folder as jpg files.

Comment: You might be able to just select the `ATT_NAME` field, which for the .gdb that I am working with has a better name and the .jpg suffix.

Comment: As William3031 said, I tested just selecting the ATT_NAME with no extra expression, and it worked flawlessly. Adding the expression gives each image an extra .jpg at the end. Still works, just an extra step that isn't needed. (Used QGIS 3.24).